# Templating Sphinx's sidebar toctree

Tags: jinja2, python-sphinx, sidebar, navigationbar, toctree

I am trying to make a new Sphinx template, which would create a custom toctree for the sidebar.

Using the Jinja templating language, there seems to be only one function available: `toctree()` which displays all the toctree at once but I need to loop through individual toctree items.

This would look like that:

```
{% for element in toctree_elements %}
    {{ ... display the stuff as wanted }}
{% endfor %}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found one trick, but it is not very satisfying.

This takes the html toctree from the function `toctree()` and removes all unwanted html tags. Only the URLs and titles are kept, and an array is created.

```
{% set theTocTree = toctree()
    | replace("</a>", "")
    | replace(" href=\"", "></a>")
    | replace("</li>", "</li>;")
    | striptags
    | replace("\">", "%") %}
{% set theTocTree = theTocTree.split(";") %}
```

Then, the following loops over the new toctree array to do whatever is needed.

```
{% for element in theTocTree %}
    {% set el = element.split("%") %}
    {% set url = el[0] | trim | safe %}
    {% set entry = el[1] | trim | safe %}
    ... here, you can use variables url and entry ...
{% endfor %}
```

This solution is unclean because it depends on the toctree html rendering, which might change in future Sphinx versions. Furthermore, it does not accept the characters `%` and `;` in URLs or toctree entries.

Answer (score 0):

[fulltoc.py](https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/fulltoc/blob/master/sphinxcontrib/fulltoc.py) in [sphinx-contrib/fulltoc](https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/fulltoc) modifies `context['toc']` by running `html_page_context` when the `html-page-context` event runs.

> Extension for Sphinx to make the sidebar show a full table of contents instead of just the local headings